# Updating multiple rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update all employees which the SQL statement brings forth. when I click the button to update it only updates the last employeeName the SQL statement gets from the database. I need to update all employee names which the SELECT SQL gets from the database. I have tried moving the submit button 'saveRota' into the while statement so a button will appear next to every name however the update statement then doesn't work

```
echo"<form method='POST' action='mng_menu1.php'>
<label><input type='text' id='monday' name='monday' ></label>
<label><input type='text'  name='tuesday' ></label>
<label> <input type='text'  name='wednesday' ></label>
<label> <input type='text'  name='thursday' ></label>
<label> <input type='text'  name='friday' </label>
<label> <input type='text'  name='saturday' </label>
<label> <input type='text'  name='sunday' </label>";
;
     if(isset($_POST['saveRota'])){

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","unn_w12014288","byron122"); // connect to the database

mysqli_select_db($con,"unn_w12014288");

$insertReq =  " UPDATE ip_rota SET mon_morn='$_POST[status]' WHERE employeeName='$_POST[employeeName]'";

mysqli_query($con, $insertReq);


}


$test= $_POST['monday'];

        if(isset($_POST['start'])) {
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "unn_w12014288", "byron122"); // connect to the database
            mysqli_select_db($con, "unn_w12014288");

            $sql = "SELECT e.employeeName, a.mon_morn
FROM ip_employee_availability a
INNER JOIN ip_employee e
ON a.employeeID = e.employeeID
WHERE a.mon_morn = 'yes'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM ip_employee_request r
            WHERE a.employeeID = r.employeeID
            AND r.requestDate = '04/18/2016'
            AND r.requestStatus = 'approved')";

            $myData = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)) {

                echo "<label>" . "<input type=text id='idtxt'  required name='employeeName' value=" . $data['employeeName'] . " </label>";
                echo "<select name='status'>
                        <option name='status' value='Rest'>Rest</option>
                        <option name='status' value='Assign'>Assign</option>
                      </select>";


            }echo"<input type='submit' name='saveRota' value='Save Rota'>";
        }


echo"<input type='submit' name='start' value='Start week'>";


 echo "</form>";
 ?>
```

Comment: missing form open tag!!

Comment: i have added the start of the from

Comment: Are you getting all employee list at view to update?

Comment: yes so the Select statement selects the specific employees i require. from that list i want to update their shifts on the ip_rota table mon_morn = $_post['status'] where employeeName = '$_POST['employeeName] '

Comment: Update query must be outside of your form!!

Comment: changed that and it doesnt make a difference\

Comment: Hey, you need learn about `mysqli_real_escape_string` here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

You closed the form: `echo "</form>";` but did not open it.

You'll need to have a open form tag:

```
echo "<form method='post'>";
```